# How to add files to bootable linux setup ISO image copied to USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting, dd, iso

I use

```
dd bs=4M if=debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdc conv=fdatasync status=progress && sync
```

to write the [debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso) ISO file to my USB flash drive and then I can boot from it and start the setup. However, I want to add some files to the USB flash drive to make them available during setup. How do I do that? The stick is somehow marked read-only and `/dev/sdc1` gets mounted as `-t iso9660`.

```
# fdisk -l debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso 
Disk debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso: 377 MiB, 395313152 bytes, 772096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x3c15dbf8

Device                           Boot Start    End Sectors  Size Id Type
debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso1 *        0 772095  772096  377M  0 Empty
debian-11.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso2       4060   9243    5184  2,5M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Comment: You will need to add them to the ISO file and then write it to the USB.

Comment: A Google search will show you how to do that.

Comment: You have found what you need to do. Rather than waiting for someone to tell you how, you can find out how to do it on your own. I could give you a link but that's something that you can find. What would you have done had no one responded?

Comment: You already know how to extract an ISO. The next apparent step is to add the files to what you've extracted which I'm sure that you can do. A Google search for "create ISO with Linux" will give you the last thing that you need. You could have done this many times over. People here will help you but you're going to have to show some initiative and try things on your own. It's why the same thing is stated when there is a question in the fashion of "How do I do this?" or "Can someone do this for me?" while the person hasn't attempted anything on one's own.

Comment: I prefer to install grub to gpt partitioned drive with ESP for UEFI boot or bios_grub for BIOS boot, make a folder for ISOs and use grub to boot those ISOs. And then depending on how many ISO & size of flash drive add another partition for data. Some tools do something similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269462/bios-uefi-template-image-for-booting-iso-files ISO boot & link to examples
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot  Or: https://askubuntu.com/questions/962536/partitioning-a-usb-and-making-separate-bootable-drives

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.